# Passing Data From Text File to Constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, constructor, text-files

I'm looking for a way to pass information from a text file into a constructor so that I can create an array of that constructor object with each object in the array holding information from the rows of the text file.

The constructor is formatted as follows:

`public Member(string name, int number, decimal rate, double hours)`

While the text file is formatted as such:

```
Eric Wallace,    352456, 15.88, 32.20
Clara Kell,     233424, 35.88, 18.76
Darren Price,   656795, 27.82, 20.25
etc...
```

and each Member will go into an array.

In the end, what I need is for each row to be split up and passed to the constructor in a way where each row becomes its own member in an array so that they can be output one after another in a loop or called individually as rows.

Comment: if the constructor is private as shown, there is not much you can do.  Might want to post some of the code you are trying to use so we can see what the actual problem is and help

Comment: In general, assuming you are doing this from within the `Member` class, you'd `Split` the string on the comma and white space.  That will give you an array of strings.  Then you'd need to interpret the second entry as an integer, the third as a decimal and the last one as a double.  Since this is external data, consider using code like `int.TryParse` and having a strategy for unparsable data.  Then create the objects and `Add` them to a `List<Member>` (a list is a much better solution here than an array)

Comment: Have you considered making a `public Member(string csvString)` constructor? In this constructor, the code parses the whole csv string to create a new `Member` object. Then you could read each line of the file and create a new `Member` object from the csv `string` read from the file then add the `Member` object to a `List<Member>`.

Comment: What surprises me about this question is that it's well written and clearly explained, but there appears to have been absolutely no attempt to solve the problem.. It's far from the usual "giv me teh codez" fare, but reading a file, splitting a string and making a new object are all quite basic things..

Comment: If a answer solves your problem mark it as accepted answer. If it helps you give it a upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would begin with making an interface that all my "buildable" data types will implement. I want my data models deciding how they are built from a string:

```
    public interface IBuildableFromString
    {
        public IBuildableFromString Build(string str, string seperator = ",");
    }
```

Then make `Member` implement it like so:

```
    public class Member : IBuildableFromString
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public double Hours { get; set; }

        public Member() { }
        public Member(string name, int number, decimal rate, double hours)
        {
            Name = name;
            Number = number;
            Rate = rate;
            Hours = hours;
        }

        public IBuildableFromString Build(string str, string seperator = ",")
        {
            try
            {
                string[] parts = str.Split(seperator);
                return new Member(parts[0], int.Parse(parts[1]), 
                    decimal.Parse(parts[2]), double.Parse(parts[3]));
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the method to read the file and build the object data:

```
        public static T[] BuildData<T>(string filePath) where T : 
                                                        IBuildableFromString, new()
        {
            List<T> dataObjects = new List<T>();
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                {
                    var newMember = new T().Build(line);
                    if (newMember != null)
                        dataObjects.Add((T)newMember);
                }
            }

            return dataObjects.ToArray();
        }
```

Lastly, call the function above like so:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = BuildData<Member>(@"path_to_your_file.txt");
        }
```

It probably needs more error checking, but this was the most extensible way I could think of doing it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your file is well-formed, then this would work:

```
Member[] members =
    File
        .ReadLines(@"mytextfile.txt")
        .Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(y => y.Trim()).ToArray())
        .Select(x => new Member(x[0], int.Parse(x[1]), decimal.Parse(x[2]), double.Parse(x[3])))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: You can skip the Trim part if you like; Parse ignores white space unless you turn it off with the NumberStyles overload

Answer (score 0):

I will use `StreamReader` to read the txt file, then use `replace` to eliminate spaces, and then use `split` to split the data.

[Use `StreamReader` to read text from a file:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0)

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\demo\de.txt")
```

[image]

Make Member implement it like so:

```
public class Member {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public decimal Rate { get; set; }
            public double Hours { get; set; }
            public Member(string name, int number, decimal rate, double hours) {
                Name = name;
                Number = number;
                Rate = rate;
                Hours = hours;
            }
        }
```

Call the data like this:

```
foreach (var item in members) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ item.Name}  { item.Number}  { item.Rate}   { item.Hours}");
            }
```

[image]

Total code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<Member> members = new List<Member>();  
            try {
                // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
                // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\demo\de.txt")) {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                    // the file is reached.
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        line = line.Replace(" ", "");
                        string[] tmp = line.Split(',');
                        string name = tmp[0];
                        int number = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1]);
                        decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(tmp[2]);
                        double hours = Convert.ToDouble(tmp[3]);
                        members.Add(new Member(name, number, rate, hours));                    
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Let the user know what went wrong.
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            foreach (var item in members) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ item.Name}  { item.Number}  { item.Rate}   { item.Hours}");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Member {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
            public decimal Rate { get; set; }
            public double Hours { get; set; }
            public Member(string name, int number, decimal rate, double hours) {
                Name = name;
                Number = number;
                Rate = rate;
                Hours = hours;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**If you have questions, please add a comment.**

Comment: Does it help you?